# Sass - via Webpack Mix - ignores options

Tags: css, webpack, laravel-mix

I am using Webpack Mix and I am attempting to set some options - `includePaths`. But it appears that sass &/or webpack mix is ignoring all these options. I know this because in my sass I have `@import url('icons/styles.css');` which should resolve to `@import url('dist/assets/icons/styles.css');` but it fails to compile with an error about not being able to locate the file.

So I then tried to set my webpack mix options to `processCssUrls: false` so it will just ignore my `url()` altogether and the same error occurs. Which leads me to believe that webpack mix is igoring my options?

Any advice on how to get sass to either resolve my `url` paths or just ignore them?

```
  let mix = require('laravel-mix');

  mix.setPublicPath('dist')
     .js('src/app.js', 'scripts/')
     .extract([
        'jquery',
        'axios',
        'babel-polyfill',
        'lodash',
        'tether',
        'vue',
        'bootstrap-vue',
        'vuex',
        'vuex-localstorage'
     ])
     // Set include paths but I still get errors
     .sass('src/styles/app.scss', 'styles/', {includePaths: ['dist/assets/']})
     .copyDirectory('src/assets', 'dist/assets')
     .options({
        // Turn off process css urls but I still get errors
        processCssUrls: false,
        uglify: true
      })
     .version();
```